# Inline-flex increases block width for no obvious reason in Chrome, how can I fix this?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I'm [playing around](http://codepen.io/shabunc/pen/lkKct) with `display: inline-flex` css property and see completely different behaviour for the same layout in Firefox and Chrome:

Here's how blocks are stacked in Firefox:
[image]

And here's how it looks like in Chrome:
[image]

So, Firefox is working as expected (at least by me), and Chrome increases the width of container for some misterious reason.

My question is - what behaviour meets specification and how I can make Chrome to render blocks just like Firefox does.

For the sake of self-completeness, here's css code from codepen snippet I've provided link to:

```
body {
  font-family: Century Gothic;
}

.adder {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.stage {
  height: 200px;
  background: linen;
  overflow: visible;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.job {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.job:nth-child(2n) {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: this seems like a bug : https://codereview.chromium.org/289903007/

Comment: @Riskbreaker thank you for this link, it looks relevant, now let see if somebody can help  with the second part of question  - how this problem could be overcomed.

Comment: inline-flex is pretty new to CSS3, it will be buggy and unpredictable. I try to avoid using anything really new until it becomes more mainstream.

Comment: @TomRudge while this is true to some extent, it is more or less stable for about at least a year. In some cases flexbox is an appropriate tool - for example, in chrome extensions. But yes, using it anytime anywhere will be a wrong decision.

Answer (score 0):

I took the time and went over to ***CodePen***, turns out your problem lies in the css, If you change  ***"display:inline-flex;"*** to ***"display:flex;"*** ***AND*** ***"align-items:flex-start;"*** to ***"align-content:flex-start;"***. I have tested the code and it definitely works on all but safari, I have tested every way I can think of to get it to work, but to no avail.

Athena

P.S. On a side note your missing a semicolon in your JS...